# What does it mean "to shade in a map" and "outline a map" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I don’t understand the meaning of this sentence. A person is disappointed, and she expresses it *like a school teacher expressing her disappointment in the sixth grader who simply shaded in her map of America without bothering to outline it, too.*
What does it mean exactly *to shade in her map of America*, and *outline it*, in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shade in is to darken or color with a pencil. This would mean that the student was handed a map of the US, maybe one that had the outline of the **country** but not the **states**, and instead of properly outlining the states the student just colors all over the map. Another possibility is that the student was supposed to draw an outline of the country and then color it, but instead just started shading/coloring it. There is a slight uncertainty here, but that's the basic idea. If I were provided the source I could possible surmise exactly what it means.

Comment: It's just a metaphor, so I can't provide more context. I think the meaning is the first you described (the map has the outline of the country but not the states, and instead of properly outlining the states the student just colors all over the map). Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help you out!